# Is it possible to return back to jelly bean OS after upgraded to cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, rooting, rom-flashing

I am using samsung galaxy Star Pro 7260 (rooted). I would like to install cyanogenmod on my phone. But, I want to know is it possible to return back to jelly bean OS after upgraded to cyanogenmod ? If it is possible then tell me what I have to do before installing cyanogenmod on my phone ? Do I have to take any backup (OS) from my phone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, this is possible the very same way as you put CyanogenMod on your device: by flashing a ROM. So before you start, make sure you either...

- have a stock ROM available to flash (see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575))
- have created a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) of your device immediately before you start flashing (requires a custom recovery, see [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode))

In both cases, you can return to stock ROM: either by flashing a stock image (and then start like after a factory-reset), or by restoring the Nandroid backup (and take off at the time you've created it, including all your apps and data).

Two things to consider:

- there *might* be dependencies between [device-firmware](/questions/tagged/device-firmware) (ROM) and [radio-firmware](/questions/tagged/radio-firmware). So if installing CyanogenMod (or any custom ROM) goes along with a different radio image, a return might be different (you might need the original radio image as well) or difficult (in case downgrade of the radio is not possible). However, cases where this applies are rare.
- Nandroid backup doesn't take care of your SDCard. So if you have apps installed on SDCard, you need to deal with them separately.

Comment: "requires a custom recovery, see recovery-menu" - what do you mean by recovery-menu?

Comment: @OndrejBozek Ouch, wrong "box". Fixed, so now you can simply click on the box or over your mouse over it to click the [info](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info) link. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score -1):

First of you need to be clear that Cyanogenmod is a custom ROM based on Android. So versions of Cyanogenmod are based on versions of Android.
e.g. CYANOGENMOD 10.1 is based on Android 4.2

So now straight to your question.

Yes you can basically do that . Once you have downloaded and flashed Clockworkmod or Twrp recovery for your phone, go in recovery by pressing a combination of hardware keys( check Samsung website or search on Google).
Go to Backup and Restore option and do a backup of your "Stock ROM" i.e. the original software of your phone. Each and everything will be backed up. But also consider doing a backup in Samsung Kies of your user data.

Now after backup you are set , go to Cyanogenmod website and select the ROM for your device and Install or Flash it as per instructions.
( besides rooting you will also need unlocking your bootloader which will void your warranty)

And anytime when you wish to remove Cyanogenmod and go back to Original ROM go in recovery and select backup and restore and press restore and select the backup file.

Your ROM will be restored as you left it.